# Tagging words/phrases in a sentence based on Regex match in Perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have the following sentence:

```
zzzzzzz  microRNA146a xxx (miR-146a, mir-33c) xxxx wwwwww Breast Cancer zzzz mir-33c kkk
```

What I want to do is to tag the words/phrases in that
sentence based on some predefined regular expression rule.
In the end it looks like this:

```
zzzzzzz  [microRNA146a]<MIR-0> xxx ([miR-146a]<MIR-1>, [mir-33c]<MIR-2>) xxxx wwwwww [Breast Cancer] <CANCER-0> zzzz [mir-33c]<MIR-2> kkk.
```

Note that in the above output each words/phrases that satisfy the rules
are indexed by the order it occur.

I'm stuck with the following code. What's the right way to do it?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;
my $text = 'zzzzzzz   microRNA146a xxx (miR-146a, mir-33c) xxxx wwwwww Breast Cancer zzzz';

# Rule 1 for miRNA definition 
my @mirlist = ($text =~ /( mir-\d+\w+| microRNA\d+)/xgi);

# Rule 2 for special words/phrases
my @spec = ($text =~ /(Breast Cancer)/gi);

# These arrays already preserve the order of occurrence
print Dumper \@mirlist ;
print Dumper \@spec ;

# Not sure how to proceed from here
```

**Update:**Add the re-occuring miRNA and refine the desired answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your own dump with a simple `for` to iterate with the 2 arrays:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
my $text = 'zzzzzzz   microRNA146a xxx (miR-146a, mir-33c) xxxx microRNA146a wwwwww Breast Cancer aaaa Breast Cancer zzzz mir-33c kkk';

# Rule 1 for miRNA definition 
my $i = 0;
$text =~ s/(mir-\d\w+|microrna\d+\w?)/"[$1]<MIR-" . $i++ . ">"/gie;

# Rule 2 for special words/phrases
my $j = 0;
$text =~ s/(breast cancer)/"[$1]<CANCER-" . $j++ . ">"/gie;

print $text;
```

[**Live DEMO.**](https://eval.in/38112)

Comment: Thanks so much. Suppose there is another occurrence of `mir-33c` at the end of the sentence. Now it prints `[[mir-33c]<MIR-3>]<MIR-2>`  How can I modify your code so that it output simply `[mir-33c]<MIR-3>` or `[mir-33c]<MIR-2>`.
Here is the test code: https://eval.in/38097

Comment: @neversaint have updated my answer with a simpler code that will not fail over repeated occurrences.

Comment: thanks so much! Sorry, but is there a way I can separate the two rules (for cancer and miRNA) into different lines of code? I have many more rules to add.

Comment: @neversaint just split into into 2 regex as you would normally.

Comment: @neversaint that's OK was nice learning about the modifier e which I was not aware of.